# onreadystatechange not getting called

Tags: javascript, ajax

i am expecting an alert box on calling the show_Message function but onreadystatechange is not working.The other alert boxes are working fine

here is my js function

```
 function send_Message(){
  var msg=document.getElementById("msg").value;
if(msg.length===0||msg===""){
    alert("please enter some message");
    return;
}

var sender=document.getElementById("username").value;
var sendto=document.getElementById("chat_id").options[document.getElementById("chat_id").selectedIndex].value;
alert(sender+" "+sendto);
var xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    alert('hello');
    if(xhttp.readyState==4 && xhttp.status==200){
        document.getElementById("chat_logs").innerHTML=xhttp.responseText;
    }
    xhttp.open('GET','send_messages.php?sender='+sender+'sendto='+sendto+'message='+msg,true);
    xhttp.send(null);
}
 }
```

Comment: You need to call xhttp.open('GET','send_messages.php?sender='+sender+'sendto='+sendto+'message='+msg,true);
    xhttp.send(null); outside of your onreadystatechange function.

Comment: how are you calling `send_message` function ??

Comment: and you need your open and send outside of onreadstatechange

Comment: thank you!! i am so stupid.. revised the code so many times still didnt got it .anyways thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

`xhttp.open('GET','send_messages.php?sender='+sender+'sendto='+sendto+'message='+msg,true);
 xhttp.send(null);`

Should be outside of `onreadystatechange`

Change it as

```
function send_Message(){
  var msg=document.getElementById("msg").value;
if(msg.length===0||msg===""){
    alert("please enter some message");
    return;
}

var sender=document.getElementById("username").value;
var sendto=document.getElementById("chat_id").options[document.getElementById("chat_id").selectedIndex].value;
alert(sender+" "+sendto);
var xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    alert('hello');
    if(xhttp.readyState==4 && xhttp.status==200){
        document.getElementById("chat_logs").innerHTML=xhttp.responseText;
    }
}
xhttp.open('GET','send_messages.php?sender='+sender+'sendto='+sendto+'message='+msg,true);
    xhttp.send(null);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have did the closing mistake. 
xhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){

Above function should close after the if statement you have.

Check corrected code below:

```
function send_Message(){
  var msg=document.getElementById("msg").value;
if(msg.length===0||msg===""){
    alert("please enter some message");
    return;
}

var sender=document.getElementById("username").value;
var sendto=document.getElementById("chat_id").options[document.getElementById("chat_id").selectedIndex].value;
alert(sender+" "+sendto);
var xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    alert('hello');
    if(xhttp.readyState==4 && xhttp.status==200){
        document.getElementById("chat_logs").innerHTML=xhttp.responseText;
    }
}; 
    xhttp.open('GET','send_messages.php?sender='+sender+'sendto='+sendto+'message='+msg,true);
    xhttp.send(null);

 }
```

Answer (score -1):

it could be because you have your open and send inside `onstatechange` function ..

```
function send_Message(){
  var msg = document.getElementById("msg").value;
  if( msg.length === 0 || msg === "" ){
    alert("please enter some message");
    return;
  }

  var sender=document.getElementById("username").value;
  var sendto=document.getElementById("chat_id").options[document.getElementById("chat_id").selectedIndex].value;
  alert(sender+" "+sendto);

  var xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    alert('hello');
    if(xhttp.readyState==4 && xhttp.status==200){
        document.getElementById("chat_logs").innerHTML=xhttp.responseText;
    }
  }

  xhttp.open('GET','send_messages.php?sender='+sender+'sendto='+sendto+'message='+msg,true);
  xhttp.send(null);
}
```